# Laravel - Custom Request ends up returning no error message

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

This is my Request:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ];
    }
}
```

And now I want to use this in my Login Post Method:

```
public function loginUser(LoginRequest $request) {
        if(empty(AuthManager::getAuthErrors())) {    
            if(!Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password'], $request->has('remember')))) {
                return view('auth.auth', ['status' => '505', 'mode' => 'login']);
            }

            return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'logged_in');
        }

        return view('auth.auth', ['status' => '505', 'mode' => 'login', 'errors' => AuthManager::getAuthErrors()]);
    }
```

And last of all, I use in the auth.auth blade like this:

```
@foreach($errors as $error)
    <div class="error">
        <p>{{ trans('auth.errors.'.$error) }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Everything is translated properly and I never get any response except when my own Responses from the AuthManager get fired, by the way the AuthManager just checks if the User is already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. If your validation fails and have problems in displaying error messages.

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="error">
        <p>{{ trans('auth.errors.'.$error) }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```